# Saving daily data for a model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an article model and a user model. The user can follow that article, but can't unfollow it. I'd like to keep track of new followers for an article, and to retrieve it for when I want to plot it. (Assume, for now, that plotting is not the problem.)

I'd like every article to have a list of the every date since that article was created. So it will have:

```
article.newfollowers[1/1/2012] = 35
article.newfollowers[2/1/2012] = 4
```

Every time a user follows an article I would do

```
This.newfollowers[Date()]++
```

Obviously saving such data means that each row in the article database has hundred of attributes (for each date).

How would I save the data within the article model? How do I declare/define such attribute?

Comment: Except there's no `++` in Ruby.

Comment: that's a new Model screaming out loud here. Unless your are dealing with a NoSQL DB like MongoDB, that you can have a Model with complex attributes like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to query for the dates directly, take a look at [ActiveRecord::Store](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html). You'll need to be using Rails 3.2.0 at least, but would prevent you from having to add so many columns.

Another solution might be to use a [Redis sorted set](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set), using the date timestamp as the score, and the new followers as the value.

Comment: redis seems a good scalable option for adding more daily attributes for a model. I'll try and report back. thanks

Comment: I've had good success with the [redis-objects](https://github.com/nateware/redis-objects) gem. Good luck!